# Sum Of count in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sum, grouping

I have the JSON data as below.

```
[

  {
    "avg": 996.8,
    "sessions": [

      {
        "minTime": 0,
        "maxTime": 599,
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "minTime": 600,
        "maxTime": 1199,
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "minTime": 1800,
        "maxTime": 2399,
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "minTime": 2400,
        "maxTime": 2999,
        "count": 3
      }
    ],"timestamp":1449360000},
  {
    "avg": 986.4,
    "sessions": [

      {
        "minTime": 0,
        "maxTime": 599,
        "count": 12
      },
      {
        "minTime": 600,
        "maxTime": 1199,
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "minTime": 1200,
        "maxTime": 1799,
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "minTime": 1800,
        "maxTime": 2399,
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "minTime": 3000,
        "maxTime": 3599,
        "count": 3
      }
    ]
    ,"timestamp":1449540000}]
```

And I need to get the data as

```
[{"avg" : 996.8,"sumcount" :19 , "timestamp":1449360000 }
{"avg": 986.4, "sumcount" :20 ,"timestamp":1449540000 }]
```

I tried ( I know the code is not correct, still adding) with `nest()` but getting the count=0

```
d3.json("Dwell.json", function(error,data){ 

var res = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.avg; })
            .rollup(function(v) { return d3.sum(v, function (d) {return d.count})})
            .entries(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
})
```

And the result is `[{"key":"996.8","values":0},{"key":"986.4","values":0}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for collecting count and mapping the objects.

```js
var data = [{ "avg": 996.8, "sessions": [{ "minTime": 0, "maxTime": 599, "count": 10 }, { "minTime": 600, "maxTime": 1199, "count": 2 }, { "minTime": 1800, "maxTime": 2399, "count": 4 }, { "minTime": 2400, "maxTime": 2999, "count": 3 }], "timestamp": 1449360000 }, { "avg": 986.4, "sessions": [{ "minTime": 0, "maxTime": 599, "count": 12 }, { "minTime": 600, "maxTime": 1199, "count": 1 }, { "minTime": 1200, "maxTime": 1799, "count": 2 }, { "minTime": 1800, "maxTime": 2399, "count": 2 }, { "minTime": 3000, "maxTime": 3599, "count": 3 }], "timestamp": 1449540000 }],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        return {
            avg: a.avg,
            sumcount: a.sessions.reduce(function (s, b) { return s + b.count; }, 0),
            timestamp: a.timestamp
        };
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You could also use a `d3.sum` to do the sumcount: `sumcount: d3.sum(a.sessions, function(d){return d.count}),`